# D3: After adding a node, drag is attached but it does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Click anywhere in the blue to add a node. It gets added. The drag **does** work -- I can console.log in dragstarted, dragged and dragended and see that it's being dragged. Even the other nodes properly move out of the phantom nodes way! But visually it just sits there.

I must be missing something fundamental. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0p7vb2s/)

```
<body>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var width = 640,
      height = 480;

  var graphNodes = [
    { id: 0, r: 5 },
    { id: 1, r: 5 },
    { id: 2, r: 5 },
    { id: 3, r: 5 },
    { id: 4, r: 5 },
    { id: 5, r: 5 },
    { id: 6, r: 5 },
    { id: 7, r: 5 },
    { id: 8, r: 5 }
  ];

  var graphEdges = [
      { source: 0, target: 1 },
      { source: 0, target: 2 },
      { source: 0, target: 3 },
      { source: 0, target: 4 },
      { source: 0, target: 5 },
      { source: 0, target: 6 },
      { source: 0, target: 7 },
      { source: 0, target: 8 }
  ];

  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

  svg.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'graph')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'lightblue')
      .attr('opacity', 0.3)
      .on('click', function(){
        graphNodes.push({ id: graphNodes.length, r: 15 });
        update(d3.mouse(this));
      });

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d, i) { return i; }))
      .force("collide",d3.forceCollide( function(d){return d.r + 8 }).iterations(16) )
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(0))
      .force("x", d3.forceX(0));

  var linkGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graphEdges)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr('stroke', 'gray')
      .attr("stroke-width", 2);

  var nodeGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graphNodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
      .attr("fill", "gray")
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start",dragstarted)
          .on("drag",dragged)
          .on("end",dragended));

  function dragstarted(d){
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    simulation.restart();
    /*d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;*/
  }

  function dragged(d){
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d){
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
    simulation.alphaTarget(0.1);
  }

  function ticked(){
    linkGroup
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    //nodeGroup.attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x;}).attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y;})
    nodeGroup.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  }

  function update(coordinates) {
    // Redefine and restart simulation
    simulation.nodes(graphNodes).on("tick", ticked);
    simulation.force("link").links(graphEdges);

    // Update links
    var link = linkGroup.selectAll("line").data(graphEdges),
        linkEnter = link.enter().append("line");

    link = linkEnter.merge(link);
    link.exit().remove();

    // Update nodes
    var node = nodeGroup.data(graphNodes),
        nodeEnter = node.enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
            .attr("fill", "gray")
            .attr('cx', coordinates[0])
            .attr('cy', coordinates[1])
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start",dragstarted)
                .on("drag",dragged)
                .on("end",dragended));

    node = nodeEnter.merge(node);
    node.exit().remove();
  }

  simulation.nodes(graphNodes).on("tick", ticked);
  simulation.force("link").links(graphEdges);

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are relying on your `ticked` event to move the nodes.  Your `ticked` event though operates on the `nodeGroup` variable.  Your click handler and `update` function, though create a local `node` variable and operate on that (ie your new entered node **is never part** of the `nodeGroup`).

Simple change in `update` is for this:

```
node = nodeEnter.merge(node);
```

to become this:

```
nodeGroup = nodeEnter.merge(node);
```

Once you fix that you'll also find you don't need to explicitly set the position of the entering node (ie you no longer need these lines):

```
.attr('cx', coordinates[0])
.attr('cy', coordinates[1])
```

Running code:

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
  var width = 640,
      height = 480;

  var graphNodes = [
    { id: 0, r: 5 },
    { id: 1, r: 5 },
    { id: 2, r: 5 },
    { id: 3, r: 5 },
    { id: 4, r: 5 },
    { id: 5, r: 5 },
    { id: 6, r: 5 },
    { id: 7, r: 5 },
    { id: 8, r: 5 }
  ];

  var graphEdges = [
      { source: 0, target: 1 },
      { source: 0, target: 2 },
      { source: 0, target: 3 },
      { source: 0, target: 4 },
      { source: 0, target: 5 },
      { source: 0, target: 6 },
      { source: 0, target: 7 },
      { source: 0, target: 8 }
  ];

  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

  svg.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'graph')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'lightblue')
      .attr('opacity', 0.3)
      .on('click', function(){
        graphNodes.push({ id: graphNodes.length, r: 15 });
        update(d3.mouse(this));
      });

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d, i) { return i; }))
      .force("collide",d3.forceCollide( function(d){return d.r + 8 }).iterations(16) )
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(0))
      .force("x", d3.forceX(0));

  var linkGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graphEdges)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr('stroke', 'gray')
      .attr("stroke-width", 2);

  var nodeGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graphNodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
      .attr("fill", "gray")
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start",dragstarted)
          .on("drag",dragged)
          .on("end",dragended));

  function dragstarted(d){
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    simulation.restart();
    /*d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;*/
  }

  function dragged(d){
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d){
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
    simulation.alphaTarget(0.1);
  }

  function ticked(){
    linkGroup
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    //nodeGroup.attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x;}).attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y;})
    nodeGroup.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  }

  function update(coordinates) {
    // Redefine and restart simulation
    simulation.nodes(graphNodes).on("tick", ticked);
    simulation.force("link").links(graphEdges);

    // Update links
    var link = linkGroup.selectAll("line").data(graphEdges),
        linkEnter = link.enter().append("line");

    link = linkEnter.merge(link);
    link.exit().remove();

    // Update nodes
    var node = nodeGroup.data(graphNodes),
        nodeEnter = node.enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
            .attr("fill", "gray")
      //      .attr('cx', coordinates[0])
      //      .attr('cy', coordinates[1])
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start",dragstarted)
                .on("drag",dragged)
                .on("end",dragended));

    nodeGroup = nodeEnter.merge(node);
    node.exit().remove();
  }

  simulation.nodes(graphNodes).on("tick", ticked);
  simulation.force("link").links(graphEdges);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's perfect - knew it must've been something in the ticked event.